# Contador dentro de una función sea global

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

tengo éste código el cual puedo agregar elementos, lo que quiero realizar es el poder eliminarlos, actualmente los puedo eliminar, pero surge un problema ya que solo doy la opción de crear 4 elementos:

```
if (id == 4) {
  btn_agregar.setAttribute("style", "visibility:hidden");
}
```

El problema surge al eliminar lo que hago es restarle al contador `id--`, pero solo se resta dentro de la función y no globalmente, entonces mi duda es como puedo hacer aquello y que se replique en la función "global".

Aquí dejo el código completo:

```js
const btn_agregar = document.getElementById("btn_add");
var id = 0;
btn_agregar.onclick = function() {
  id++;

  $(document).on('click', '#btn_delete' + id, function() {
    var section = document.getElementById("section" + id);
    section.remove();
    id--;
    console.log(id);
  });

  if (id == 4) {
    btn_agregar.setAttribute("style", "visibility:hidden");
  }

  $(document).on('click', '#btn_add', function() {
    $("#section" + id).html("");
    var $section = $(
      '<hr>' +
      '<div class="form-row mt-4">' +
      '<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 mt-4 mt-sm-0">' +
      '<label>&nbsp;Ejemplo' + id + '</label>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="form-row mt-4">' +
      '<div class="col">' +
      '<button type="button" id="btn_delete' + id + '" class="btn btn-link float-left" style="color: #E53212">Eliminar [-]</button>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>'
    );
    $("#section" + id).append($section);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-row mt-4">
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 mt-4 mt-sm-0">
    <label>&nbsp;Ejemplo</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="section_activos"></div>

<div id="section1"></div>

<div id="section2"></div>

<div id="section3"></div>

<div id="section4"></div>

<div class="form-row mt-4">
  <div class="col">
    <button type="button" id="btn_add" class="btn btn-link float-right">Agregar [+]</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `id` es global porque dices que actúa de manera local?

Comment: @FranAcuna porque en el ejemplo si elimino algún elemento, este no resta el id global, y ya no se pueden crear 4 elementos

Comment: Eso no será por ese has ocultado el botón?

Comment: @christian claro, pero si te fijas en el ejemplo, si le das al botón Agregar se crea el label "Ejemplo 1", luego elimínalo, y vuelve a cliquear el botón Agregar, éste te crea el label "Ejemplo 2", pero debiese ser "Ejemplo 1". (Por lo que quiere decir que no se va restando el id).

Comment: @Javier El `id` si disminuye, lo sé por la consola.

Comment: @DanielBriceño si, eso está claro, el tema es como poder hacer que el id que está fuera de la función también disminuya

Comment: Creo que el problema no esta en el `id`. Tu solo declara una variable `id` tu no declaras mas, por lo que modificas esa variable siemple.... ¿Puedo intentar darte una solucion sin usar jquery. solo [JS]? La verdad no se mucho de jquery, pero entiendo la idea.

Comment: @DanielBriceño adelante, cualquier ayuda sirve!

Comment: Usa `innerHTML=""` en vez de `remove`  y que tal si colocas el `onclick` directo en el html: [Mi respuesta](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dabl03/Classic-juego/main/respuesta1.html). En tu codio cada vez que precionas un boton sin importar cual sea llama a la funcion principal lo que causa que se aumente la variable `id` sin importar si es la funcion eliminar o eso creo. Nota: si estoy equivocado por favor corrigeme.

Comment: una recomendacion utiliza templates string para el html en js :)

Comment: @christian Muchas gracias por la recomendacion. ¿Te refieres a esto: ` ${id} `?

Comment: @DanielBriceño si pero con todo lo que esta en la funcion del ```#btn_add```

Comment: Si Dios quiere mañana lo hago. @christian Muchas gracias por el consejo que desconocia esa funcion del `JS` hasta mañana.

Comment: ok amigo descanza

Comment: @christian Intento hacerlo pero me genera error. La verdad creo que lo voy a dejar así por ahora.

Comment: Ok no te preocupes, una recomendación trata de ser más ordenado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

le hice 2 cambios a tu código:

1. Hice una función global que se llama "mostrar" que es la que evalúa si se muestra el botón o no, y la llamo tanto al agregar una sección como al eliminarla.
2. La rutina de borrado hice que no dependa del "id" para eliminar el contenido, mejor accede 3 niveles hacia arriba y limpia el contenido de la sección. No es muy bonito, pero es rápido y puedes eliminar las secciones en el orden que quieras.

```js
const btn_agregar = document.getElementById("btn_add");
var id = 0;

function mostrar(){
  btn_agregar.setAttribute("style", id == 4 ? "visibility:hidden" : "visibility:visible");
}

btn_agregar.onclick = function() {
  id++;

  $(document).on('click', '#btn_delete' + id, function() {
    $(this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement).html("");
    id--;
    mostrar(); // evalúas y muestras aquí
  });

  mostrar();

  $(document).on('click', '#btn_add', function() {
    $("#section" + id).html("");
    var $section = $(
      '<hr>' +
      '<div class="form-row mt-4">' +
      '<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 mt-4 mt-sm-0">' +
      '<label>&nbsp;Ejemplo' + id + '</label>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="form-row mt-4">' +
      '<div class="col">' +
      '<button type="button" id="btn_delete' + id + '" class="btn btn-link float-left" style="color: #E53212">Eliminar [-]</button>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>'
    );
    $("#section" + id).append($section);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-row mt-4">
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 mt-4 mt-sm-0">
    <label>&nbsp;Ejemplo</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="section_activos"></div>

<div id="section1"></div>

<div id="section2"></div>

<div id="section3"></div>

<div id="section4"></div>

<div class="form-row mt-4">
  <div class="col">
    <button type="button" id="btn_add" class="btn btn-link float-right">Agregar [+]</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

estas removiendo todo el section por eso te sale ese error lo corecto seria eliminar solo el contenido del section, lo cual quedaría así

```
const btn_agregar = document.getElementById("btn_add");
var id = 0;

btn_agregar.onclick = function() {
  id++;

  $(document).on('click', '#btn_delete' + id, function() {
    var section = document.getElementById("div" + id);
    section.remove();
    id--;
    console.log(id);
  });

  if (id == 4) {
    btn_agregar.setAttribute("style", "visibility:hidden");
  }

  $(document).on('click', '#btn_add', function() {
    $("#section" + id).html("");
    var $section = $(
      '<hr>' +
      '<div class="row" id="div'+id+'">' +
      '<div class="form-row mt-4">' +
      '<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 mt-4 mt-sm-0">' +
      '<label>&nbsp;Ejemplo' + id + '</label>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="form-row mt-4">' +
      '<div class="col">' +
      '<button type="button" id="btn_delete' + id + '" class="btn btn-link float-left" style="color: #E53212">Eliminar [-]</button>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>'
    );
    $("#section" + id).append($section);
  });
}
```

Comment: creo que lo mejor seria seleccionar el hijo de ```section``` y eliminarlo a el, ya que si haces referencia a un elemento dentro de el y lo eliminas luego tendras un error

Comment: pero los hijos del section tambien son elementos que tendría que eliminar no veo la diferencia

Comment: si haces ```var el = document.getElementById("section"+id)``` y luego seleccionas a sus hijos ```el.children``` te devuelve un ```HTMLCollection``` y en caso no tenga hijos te lo devuelve vacio

Comment: y luego como lo eliminas o remueves

Comment: buen punto no habia tomado eso en cuenta, disculpa, pero igual considero que seria mejor acceder a su hijo asi evitas llamar al elemento y posibles errores si se manipula el html